# Why is babel transforming default arguments this way?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

Babel is transpiling my ES2015 default arguments to ES5, but it seems to be doing it very verbosely. Here's the original function:

```
function initStyles(skipScaling = false) {/*...*/}
```

And here is the result after transpiling:

```
function initStyles() {
  var skipScaling = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : false;
}
```

If I were to (perhaps naively) implement this, I would do something like this:

```
function initStyles(skipScaling) {
  if (skipScaling === undefined) skipScaling = false;
}
```

What's the reason Babel handles it this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameters that have a default initialiser are not counted for the function arity. The [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of your `initStyles` function should be `0`, and Babel replicates that by using the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to initialise a `var` instead of using a named parameter.

Comment: @Nick Mostly "because the spec says so". But it makes sense not to count defaulted parameters for the "expected number of arguments". Similarly, it doesn't count a rest parameter.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense.

Answer (score -1):

To add some illustration to what @Bergi mentioned it is related to "the number of arguments expected by the function" `Function.prototype.length`.

(It was `arity` in the past but now obsolete).

In an ES6 environment,

```
function foo(s = 123) { 
  console.log(arguments, s) 
}

console.log("foo.length", foo.length);
```

would print out `0` at the end.

The way Babel or Traceur translate it:

```
function foo() {
  var s = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : 123;
  console.log(arguments, s);
}

console.log("foo.length", foo.length);
```

it would also print out `0` at the end.

If written this way:

```
function bar(s) {
  if (s === undefined) s = 123;
  console.log(arguments, s);
}

console.log("bar.length", bar.length);
```

Then it'd print out `1` at the end so it is not entirely the same as ES6.